# How do I get a happy ending in Bandersnatch?

Tags: ending, black-mirror, black-mirror-bandersnatch

In *Black Mirror: Bandersnatch*, whatever I pick I end up with Stefan being in jail with one or multiple murders and his game failed, either due to his crimes or due to its being incomplete.

But what is the path to pick where the table can be turned with a happy ending or endings?

Comment: In its current form, this question might not be all too on-topic here, seeing how it's basically asking how to win an interactive game with little to no relation to the actual film material. Unless you're able to draw a clearer connection to the film material, [gaming.se] would probably be a better fit for this.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson it's an interactive film, not an interactive game

Comment: @AnkitSharma Well, it's both actually. And the nature of the question seems to be more about the game aspect, not the film.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson it's a film in netflix so I disagree

Comment: Related meta discussion: [How do we handle interactice films?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4404/49)

Comment: I haven't seen bandersnatch but heard about it. I am assuming each choice plays a role in the plot progression & the end. So, it's asking what choices if made in-universe could lead to the character not being convicted. It's similar to asking why Strange didn't bind Thanos in a time loop. It's asking about Strange's choice & why he didn't choose different & what could happen if he chose different. Looks on-topic. The wording might be taken as POB but the underlying question definitely isn't POB

Comment: @KharoBangdo Feel free to share your views on the meta discussion.

Comment: IMO it's an interactive film whose alternate reality and video game concepts within the film, is echoed by making us the pseudo game-players, infringing on Stephen's life, in which certain versions also let Stephen know this! It's both, but it's apart of Black Mirror and we do "view" the film footage so I think it should still qualify as TV/Film episode and trying to get a different ending relates to the nature of both as well. Just think of it as "different cuts"

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[Lifehacker.com](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-watch-every-ending-of-black-mirror-bandersnatc-1831380467) has provided a "road map" of sort which, if I read it correctly, does have some "non-bad" options but that's a subjective issue.

[image]

Comment: Followed few of the lifehack option and I will say the only happiesh ending is Netflix with mike as no death or jail.

Comment: My first (and so far only go around) gave a bittersweet ending depending on how one interprets it. Stephen was able to time travel and save his mother, but then the scene cuts back to a therapy session where he is found dead in a chair. So either he dreamed this while dying or both things happened simultaneously. (very Donnie Darko, if you ask me).

Comment: @DarthLocke I only got to know where he go with his mom and the cut to black, die with her

Comment: It's acknowledged that the flowchart is a **work in progress**.

Comment: Spotted a mistake in the flowchart; taking the medication from the psychiatrist gives Bandersnatch a 2.5/5 star rating, no death and no murder (at least for me). Felt like a decent ending to me.

Comment: I'm sure I had the P.A.C.S. ending after choosing Netflix and "Tell him more" (with entering "PAC" into safe earlier).

Comment: @DarthLocke It's Stefan. But that's okay, lots of people get that wrong.

Comment: Ya, sorry. I edited my answer too, once I saw how it was written. Thanks!

Comment: There is also a secret ending, see: [What is the secret ending of Black Mirror: Bandersnatch?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/98240/1799)

Answer (score 30):

Encouraged by a comment, I thought I'd try to turn my comment into an answer. The answer to the question is:

**Black Mirror doesn't make happy endings.**

I'd argue that is one of their calling cards, and one of the strong points of the series. The shows are heavy in terms of topics, and the overall theme of the show (technology isn't necessarily making things better) is emphasized in nearly every ending of the show.

Even the rare episode that ends on a 'less sad' ending (such as San Junipero) is seen as an anomaly as [Variety critic Sonia Saraiya points out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Junipero#Analysis) (emphasis added):

> Variety critic Sonia Saraiya pointed out that technology is portrayed
>   as good in "San Junipero", *a rarity in the show*.

Bottom line? Black Mirror is usually about unhappy endings. Enjoy the ride for what it is.

Comment: Many of them can be considered to have happy endings, depending on your perspective. "Hang the DJ" has the POV characters "passing" and their counterparts presumably starting a successful relationship, "Facepalm" sees the MC rejecting the system, "Black Museum" sees the "bad guy" being killed and several prisoners of the museum released, etc.

Comment: USS Callister has a happy ending too. I also thought Nosedive had a really uplifting ending with the protagonist ironically finding freedom inside a jail cell.

Comment: Some also have an open ending, like Arkangel (probably debatable) and most importantly: Smithereens

Answer (score 7):

Although I don't believe these are all the possible endings, as I have come across other people who claim to get even more mash-ups than this and because sometimes it makes you go back and then gives you new options, the following video does discuss many scenarios, citing that there really aren't any happy endings.

---

However, my experience, which I wrote all my choices down and plan to go back through just to reconfirm, allowed for Stefan to time travel back as a boy and take the train with his mother, but instead of cutting to black and implying that Stefan died with mother on the train as others have expressed in their versions, mine cuts back to a therapy session, in which Stefan was found dead!

It appears my ending could be interpreted as bittersweet if we believe that Stefan died in one time line ultimately to live the way he wanted in another, but it also could be interpreted that Stefan dreamed this, while dying.  This ending reminds me though of two other time travel films such as *Donnie Darko* or *The Jacket* in which main characters do sacrifice themselves for a different alternate reality.

Answer (score 2):

Bandersnatch is working in the archetype of the addictive meme, similar to “The Parrot” (feel free to google the image, it is safe, hard Sapir-whorf doesn’t exist). These stories are stories where a compelling text or meta-text compels the focus character and threatens to compel the reader. They often involve recursive infection and infection “unto the seventh generation.”

As observed Black mirror don’t do happy endings. Well, they don’t do happy endings inside the text, usually.  But Bandersnatch cues us early on about the infective meme. You can read this as early as the “do you understand how choose your own adventures work” screen where you are compelled to respond in a preprogrammed manner. The text offers us a solid clue (cue) here about how to read a happy ending: cease permutation and reject the text. A similar situation occurs when you pour coffee on the computer before anyone has started dying. This is another clue to reject the text.

Consider, as a relevant equivalent text, how Undertale deals with the reader recursively reading the text. Even if a spoiler switch isn’t set to 1 and the game is completed, the ending will indicate that the player will probably attempt to reread the text with the spoiler switch set to 1. Each ending is necessarily as horrific as the worst end because the reader will reread the text for the plurality of endings (or at least be made aware of this in Bandersnatch through the rerouting ending system).

Thus, the only winning move is not to play. The only happy ending is to stop the media file early, hard, and never return to it. In this case Black mirror have made a happy ending possible. It is Black mirrors’ viewers who make the unhappy endings inevitable.

Comment: "Stop watching" isn't really an answer IMO.

Comment: @F1Krazy It is very much one when we consider the special interactive nature of the film, as the answer explains sufficiently.

Answer (score 1):

The happiest ending is when Stefan reaches the maximum score for *Bandersnatch*. I mean, that was what he always wanted, not just the maximum score, but to put the same idea of the *Bandersnatch* book in his game.

Only after he killed his father he can work with calm, bring the game on time... etc. And the principal idea of the movie is revelated to us again when his therapist congratulates Stefan for finishing the game and asks him about the finale. "What the gamer doesn't know is I always control his destiny... yes, it has a happy ending" more or less said Stefan.

That's the way it is in the game, which Stefan creates; in the novel, where Pax is controling the destiny of the characters; and in the movie, which is made by Netflix. In the end, who decides how it ends is them, not us.

To make it, in the game you have to kill Stefan's father and butcher him. For a more detailed explanation please refer to the scheme above.