# How many options actually exist?

Tags: black-mirror, black-mirror-bandersnatch

The interactive Netflix film *Black Mirror: Bandersnatch* has many points where the user has to choose the path the story will take.

Some of these choices make little difference to the overall path but still require different versions of the following scene to be shot. Others create extra complexity in the future by modifying future choices. Some seem to allow a very large number of viewer choices (one scene involves choosing a multi-digit (5 or 6 digits?) phone number which implies a very large number of choices and scenes to be shot.)

The combinations seem to create a large space of possible events with many possible outcomes. This implies a large number of scenes needed to be shot even if we ignore the choices where little is changed by the choice.

So, how much footage is there? How many possible paths exist? Will we ever find them all?

Comment: Downvotes are fine, but it is always helpful to know why. And for those voting to close because it is "opinion based", how so? This is quite like asking about the alternative versions of, say, Blade Runner: it isn't about *opinion*, it is about *concrete* material that exists and can be discovered.

Comment: I absolutely don't see why this gets downvoted and even less how it could remotely be seen as "primarily opinion-based". The amount of footage shot and number of possible paths is a straight *fact*, no matter if people uninvolved in the production will have a hard time finding out. The nature of this question isn't in any way different from the ones asking what ending is "canon" or how to achieve the "best" ending (which if anything seems more opinion-based than this one). I feel like I'm really missing something here, so maybe the close-voters could enlighten me what's wrong with it.

Comment: This already has a flowchart at https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/95986/how-do-i-get-a-happy-ending-in-bandersnatch

Comment: @JasonPSallinger Yes there is. But it is clearly incomplete; it doesn't represent the complex way past choices influence future options and their content; and doesn't tell us anything about the *total* amount of content available.

Comment: There are several flowcharts already published - this [*terrible british sensationalist* ;) newspaper, the Daily Mail](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-6542169/Black-Mirrors-Bandersnatch-fans-create-detailed-flowchart-possible-endings.html) links to several

Comment: @Tetsujin And having been through the programme with the best of those flowcharts, I know even it is far from being complete.

Comment: @matt_black - I don't have a device to watch it on, so I guess I'll never know. As a huge Black Mirror fan since s01e01 call me 'miffed'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a happy ending in Bandersnatch?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/95986/how-do-i-get-a-happy-ending-in-bandersnatch)

Comment: @CanadianLuke I don't see how. It's related, though.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### *"So, how much footage is there? How many possible paths exist? Will we ever find them all?"*

> "**I don’t know how many endings there actually are — I think I’ve
> forgotten,” Brooker**, the creator and writer of the Emmy-winning
> series, tells [The Hollywood Reporter](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/black-mirror-bandersnatch-charlie-brooker-talks-interactive-movie-1171496). When his producing partner,
> Annabel Jones, suggests to THR there are five “definitive” ends,
> Brooker interrupts: “No. There are more than that.”...
>
> **Even Netflix says that while there are five “main” endings, there are
> multiple variants on each that they are daring viewers to uncover.** And
> Brooker and Jones are clear as to not “prescribe” one ending over the
> others, especially because they couldn’t agree on what exactly defines
> one.

This seems exceedingly hard to determine since everyone who worked on the project doesn't seem to agree or even know! Creator & writer Charles Brooker and Netflix claim there are about 5 definite endings, but producer Russell McLean says there are 10-12 endings, because some are less definite. Director David Slade mentions that we may never see every ending, because there are "golden eggs" that seemingly have yet to be "unlocked"

> If you ask producer Russell McLean, there are 10 to 12 endings because
> some are less definitive. **And director David Slade says there are even
> “golden eggs” that are so difficult to reach, they may never be
> unlocked. “There are scenes that some people just will never see and
> we had to make sure that we were OK with that.** We actually shot a
> scene that we can’t access,” Slade said when the team introduced the
> episode to a group of reporters, including THR's, at Netflix’s
> headquarters in Los Gatos, California.

**But in terms of actual footage shot, there is seemingly 150 minutes of "unique footage" divided into 250 segments.** Some stories are as short as 40 minutes, while the average run time is 90 minutes, however at least one story goes for 2 and half hours!

> [Bandersantch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Mirror:_Bandersnatch) is presented as an interactive film. A brief tutorial,
> specific to the device being streamed on, explains to the viewer how
> to make choices. They have ten seconds to make choices, or a default
> decision is made. Once a playthrough ends, the viewer is given an
> option of going back and making a different choice. **The average
> viewing is 90 minutes, though the quickest path ends after 40 minutes,
> and at least one path results in a 2.5-hour viewing experience.**
> **There are 150 minutes of unique footage divided into 250 segments.**
> IGN reports that according to Netflix, there are five "main" endings,
> with variants within each ending; such endings may be intercut with
> credits, similar to other Black Mirror episodes. Producer
> Russell McLean said there are between ten and twelve endings, some of
> which are more vague as endings compared to others, and according to
> director David Slade, there are a few "golden eggs" endings that may
> take a long time before viewers figure out how to achieve them. No
> ending is considered "prescribed" over any other, according to
> executive producers Charlie Brooker and Annabel Jones, particularly as
> they felt some endings were not truly endings in the traditional
> sense.

Comment: "and at least one path results in a 2.5-hour viewing experience. There are 150 minutes of unique footage" So there's a path that shows all of the footage?

Comment: @Acccumulation you have to account for 10 seconds of "frozen time" between choices. They can quickly add up. Another source (see the answer by BCdotWEB) points at even more footage.

Comment: @Mindwin I think you mean they can quickly accumulate.

Comment: @Acccumulation That 2.5 hours of viewing includes a number of repeated scenes.

Comment: @Acccumulation [This article](https://www.heise.de/newsticker/meldung/Black-Mirror-Bandersnatch-Interaktiver-Film-und-Videospiel-4259945.html) says that there are nearly 5 hours of material spread over all possible views. The same can be read in the answer of BCdotWEB

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the article! I do wonder if they mean "repeated" footage though, but 5 hours exceeds both 150 mins and/or the 2.5 hour story, so I do find that detail still uniquely contradictory to what Wiki states!

Comment: Re golden egg, check: [What is the secret ending of Black Mirror: Bandersnatch?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/98240/1799)

Answer (score 11):

[The makers decline to offer specifics](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/black-mirror-bandersnatch-charlie-brooker-talks-interactive-movie-1171496):

> If you ask producer Russell McLean, there are 10 to 12 endings because
>   some are less definitive. And director David Slade says **there are even
>   “golden eggs” that are so difficult to reach, they may never be
>   unlocked. “There are scenes that some people just will never see and
>   we had to make sure that we were OK with that. We actually shot a
>   scene that we can’t access,”** Slade said when the team introduced the
>   episode to a group of reporters, including THR's, at Netflix’s
>   headquarters in Los Gatos, California.
>
> Even Netflix says that while there are five “main” endings, there are
>   multiple variants on each that they are daring viewers to uncover. And
>   Brooker and Jones are clear as to not “prescribe” one ending over the
>   others, especially because they couldn’t agree on what exactly defines
>   one.
>
> “There were quite heated debates about what constitutes an 'ending,'”
>   says Brooker. “There’s a school of thought that says any time it stops
>   and you go back, that’s an ending. In Bandersnatch, there are endings
>   that are really abrupt that are still endings, in my mind.”
>
> Besides, Jones points out: “In a world of parallel realities, maybe
>   there is no ending?”

[iO9 adds](https://io9.gizmodo.com/we-may-never-see-all-of-black-mirror-bandersnatch-1831402962):

> While this might be frustrating, it doesn’t seem surprising. The
>   episode reportedly has about five hours of prepared footage. I played
>   through the entire thing, including [all of these endings](https://www.reddit.com/r/blackmirror/comments/ab49mh/endings/), to the best
>   of my ability and capped out around four hours. There are several
>   places where other Easter eggs could come into the picture, like with
>   Stefan’s dad’s locked box, or the phone number used to call the
>   therapist. Plus, some fan sleuths have pointed out [behind the scenes
>   footage](https://www.reddit.com/r/blackmirror/comments/ab5sxc/did_this_scene_from_bandersnatch_get_dropped_on/) that could point to other scenes we haven’t even seen yet.
>
> And for anyone looking to have all the answers handed to them at some
>   point, I’ve got some bad news: Showrunner Charlie Brooker confirmed to
>   THR that they will not be releasing a linear version of Black Mirror:
>   Bandersnatch. What we see now is all we’re going to get.